# Setting up VLAN on C sockets, receiving it on other end

Tags: c, sockets, networking, network-programming

I want to set up a C socket so that I can add 802.1Q priority tags to the UDP packets that I'll be sending through it. This is what I'm doing:

```
struct ifreq ifr;
memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
snprintf(ifr.ifr_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name), "wlan0.10");
ret = setsockopt(mSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, (void *)&ifr, sizeof(ifr));
if (ret < 0) {
    errorMsg << " Set socket options error: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
    log(errorMsg.str());
}

// this is only effective if the OS has VLAN enabled and VLAN is in use on the interface
const int VLAN_VOIP_PRIORITY = 5;
ret = setsockopt(mSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_PRIORITY, &VLAN_VOIP_PRIORITY, sizeof(VLAN_VOIP_PRIORITY));
if (ret < 0) {
    errorMsg << " Set socket options error: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
    log(errorMsg.str());
}
```

wlan0.10 is a virtual network I've set up using:

```
vconfig add wlan0 10
ip addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev wlan0.10
```

Now, I have no idea if it's working. I tried using Wireshark both on the source and destination ends of the stream, and I can't see it (when listening on the source, I listened both on wlan0 and wlan0.10, no luck). If I remove the SO_BINDTODEVICE above though, I can see it just fine, but then I can't see any indication of the SO_PRIORITY having any effect on Wireshark either.

Comment: 802.1Q tags don't have anything to do with UDP. The tags work for _some_ layer-2 LAN protocols, e.g. ethernet, but UDP is a layer-4 protocol, and it is blissfully unaware of layer-2. Also, unless your ethernet switch is configured to use the tags and has trunks configured on interfaces, the priorities mean nothing, and they are stripped at layer-3 (e.g. routers).

Answer (score 2):

`setsockopt(mSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_PRIORITY` would set the internal sk_priority for the packet in the kernel IP stack, not the vlan priority.

One of the things you can do with this internal priority is to map it to a vlan priority with the [vconfig](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man8/vconfig.8.php) `set_egress_map` command

Comment: Thanks. Am I right to use SO_BINDTODEVICE, then? Will doing that mean that the vlan tag "10" (per my example) will be added to the Ethernet frame?

Comment: I would guess no. You'll need to configure an IP address/subnet mask on your vlan interface, if you send traffic to something on that subnet, linux will route it out the vlan interface (with a vlan tag). If you're sending things to something that's not on the subnet of your vlan interface, you need to set up the routing table so packets get routed over your vlan interface (and not somewhere else, e.g. a default gateway on another interface)

Answer (score 0):

You could set the priority via SIOCSIFVLAN.

```
For eg) lets assume VLAN is eth0.10
Sample code as below

struct vlan_ioctl_args vlan_args;
setsockopt(sock_fd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_PRIORITY, &priority,sizeof(priority);
vlan_args.cmd=SET_VLAN_EGRESS_PRIORITY_CMD;
vlan_args.u.skb_priority=priority;
vlan_args.qos=qos;
vlan_args.u.name_type=VLAN_NAME_TYPE_RAW_PLUS_VID;
strcpy(vlan_args.device1,"eth0.10");

ioctl (sock_fd,SIOCSIFVLAN, &vlan_args);
```

You can then confirm if the egress priority is set by checking
cat /proc/net/vlan/eth0.10